# How to modify the country list and their id?

Tags: county

I would like to edit the country list to add some countries, for example British West Indies. How do I do that? directly into the table civicrm_country?

I also want to know if I can add my own dropdown custom field with my own key-value country list. It seems I can only add 10 choices, and then one by one. Isn´t there a way to paste my key-value country list into a field?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obviously edit the data directly in the table. Extension https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.general.api.country provides an API for Country, you could use that as well